# Raspberry PI cant connect to Wifi after completing access point set up

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, raspbian-jessie, internet

I'm new to this. I followed this documentation to set up as a stand alone access point network.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

However, after that, I am unable to use my Raspberry Pi and connect to the internet. I wanted to download an IDE on my Raspberry Pi.

How do I enable back my wifi? I know that due to setting up of access point, it disabled my wifi capability.

Comment: Was WiFil working before hand?  If so, it's likely that the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf got deleted or changed.

Comment: Yes it was working beforehand. Ahh, so the only way to fix it is by re-flashing the Raspian OS onto the microsd?

Comment: Not at all.  You can sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and add the appropriate stuff in there. I don't recall off the top of my head what goes there but you can google "wpa_supplicant.conf" and get what you need.

Comment: Oh that's great! I will try it tomorrow and let you know if it works! thanks

Comment: @CharlieHorse I managed to solve the problem! Thanks alot man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following CharlieHorse's comment, I did the following:

Turns out, it was because i changed the wlan0 codes while setting it up as an access point. This is what i did. I revert the settings back to default on my

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces using the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251320/default-settings-raspberry-pi-etc-network-interfaces

Then, in sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf, i removed:

denyinterfaces wlan0

I reboot, and my wifi is back to normal! :)

Comment: If you followed that ancient link your "restored" your Pi to obsolete settings! These do work, but disable some of the newer fearures. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) In future whenever changing config files **save a copy of the original**.